# Add css using Onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How change code CSS` in JavaScript?

**HTML :**

```
<input type="text" name="text_field"  value="text" id ="hd" />

<div id="color">
    <input type="text" name="color" class ="border-bottom" value=""/>
</div>
```

**Javascript :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#color input').change(function(){
          var css = $(this).attr("class");
          var z   = string(css);  // change type to string
          var x   = z+': 1px solid'; // mix 
          $("#hd").css(css,$(this).val());
     });
});
```

I need write `1px solid` in field, I try mix from `border-bottom` and `1px solid` to new variable (`border-bottom : 1px solid`), then I just input color type like red/blue/dll.

Please see here for more understanding https://jsfiddle.net/1Lmhj3xp/1/

Comment: `+px` ? Did you miss that ?

Comment: @RayonDabre I try make it default `border-bottom:1px solid`, so user only input color for underline

Comment: Cant understand what you want :) Maybe this can be helpful: https://jsfiddle.net/8hrmgko4/

Comment: @BobSponge yeach like that, thx so much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `(css, x + this.value)` to set the css.

```js
$('#color input').change(function() {
  var css = $(this).attr("class");
  var x = '1px solid '; // mix 
  $("#hd").css(css, x + this.value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="text_field" value="text" id="hd" />
<br><br>
<div id="color">
  <input type="text" name="color" class="border-bottom" value="" placeholder="Enter color"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `change` event not made to track change in text fields you should use  `keypress` or `ipnput` event instead  :

```
$('#color input').on('input', function(){
```

If you want to just input color you could fix `1px solid` to be static:

```
$("#hd").css(css, "1px solid "+$(this).val());
```

Hope this helps.

---

### Snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#color input').on('input', function(){
        var css = $(this).attr("class");
        $("#hd").css(css, "10px solid "+$(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
TEXT <input type="text" name="text_field"  value="text" id ="hd" />

<div id="color">
 CSS <input type="text" name="color" class ="border-bottom" value=""/>
</div>
Try input in CSS 1px solid red (onchange)
```